# Jquery : edit a table row does not work on a new row

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

I'm using jQuery to add or edit rows on a table. If I try to edit a row already here it works but if I add a new row the edit does not work.

My scripts :

```
//Add a row
$("#btnadd").click(function(){

$('.table tr:last').after('<tr>' +
    "<td>Name</td>"+    
'</tr>');
});

 //Edit a row (took from a tutorial)
$(function () {
    $("td").dblclick(function () {
        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

        $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
        $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
        $(this).children().first().focus();

        $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var newContent = $(this).val();
                $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
            }
        });

    $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
        $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
    });
    });
});
```

I'm quite new to Jquery so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('table').on('click','tr', function(){
    $(this).css('color','green');
});

$('button').on('click',function(){
    var newRow = $('<tr class="row"><td>New</td><td>Row</td><td>29</td></tr>');
    $('table').append(newRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Add</button>
```

I presume this is because the click-event is bound to the table when the page loads. Any new rows you enter after the page is loaded is missing this event. Now your function is triggered when clicking the TR (table row). Since that (new) table row doesn't exist when the page is loaded the event doesn't get bound to the new row.

You can fix this by binding the click-event to the table. By doing it this way, it will work. I made a fiddle where a tr is green if you click it. It also works with newly added table rows

```
$('table').on('click','tr', function(){
       //do your edits
});
```

I think you made a slight mistake in the copy since your click function where you add the row is not closed properly?

Comment: You are right, I forgot "});". Thanks for you answer but it's not working : with $('table') it makes me edit the full table when I just want to edit a row.